# Multiple form_tags on one page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

Say I have two form_tag 's on a page, each like this:

```
  = form_tag({:action => :import}, :multipart => true) do
    = file_field_tag 'file'
    = submit_tag 'Import', name: 'import_this'
```

So I know how that comes through in params but If I had two forms and each form had same name fields, how can I sort of namespace them in the resulting params array and how would I access them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to differentiate between the two forms, you would need to create different names for the fields.

The most common practice is to nest the fields into a 'namespace', like this:

```
  = form_tag({:action => :import}, :multipart => true) do
    = file_field_tag 'form1[file]'
    = submit_tag 'Import', name: 'form1[import_this]'
```

And the second form:

```
  = form_tag({:action => :import}, :multipart => true) do
    = file_field_tag 'form2[file]'
    = submit_tag 'Import', name: 'form2[import_this]'
```

Then in the controller, you would access them like this:

```
params[:form1][:file]
```

or

```
params[:form2][:file]
```

**Remember** that you can't submit both forms at the same time.

Comment: +1, but just as an alternative, rather than having differently named param hashes, you could always just drop in a hidden input with the form name.